# Django inspectdb ругается при генерации моделей.

Tags: django, mysql

Всем привет!
Есть БД с 50 таблицами, руками описывать модели не хочется, поэтому решил прибегнуть к генерации моделей средствами django.

вызываю ./manage.py inspectdb

Сгенерировав пару моделей ругается так:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 62, in handle_inspection
    relations = connection.introspection.get_relations(cursor, table_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 82, in get_relations
    other_field_index = self._name_to_index(cursor, other_table)[other_field]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 71, in _name_to_index
    return dict([(d[0], i) for i, d in enumerate(self.get_table_description(cursor, table_name))])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 48, in get_table_description
    AND character_maximum_length IS NOT NULL""", [table_name])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xD1\x82 \xD0\xB4...' for column 'COLUMN_COMMENT' at row 1
```

Как это победить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в одном из комментариев к полю таблицы был неправильный символ, ну, т.е., коммент написан на русском языке, но был еще какой-то спец-символ. Его удаление решило проблему